# Can I find out what Perl IO Layer(s) a given filehandle has?

Tags: perl

Is it possible to find out what IO Layer a Perl filehandle has on it?

For example:

```
open(my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $filename)
    or die "Unable to open '$filename': $!";

say io_layer($fh); # prints "encoding(UTF-8)"
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following returns the names of the PerlIO layers on a filehandle.

```
my @layers = PerlIO::get_layers($fh); # Or FH, *FH, "FH".
```

more details in [PerlIO doc](http://perldoc.perl.org/PerlIO.html).